# Same height for row in box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have free box and content in it, but I need to do same height for row in it. Now is same height only box, but I need to do same height for row in box. In example which is bellow I have blue row, which is row where I need to do same height for it and keep them on the same line with the same height.

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
}

.box {
  background:red;
}

.row {
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="row"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore explicabo quam aut cum pariatur blanditiis possimus</p></div>
    <div class="row"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="row"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore explicabo quam aut cum pariatur blanditiis possimus</p></div>
    <div class="row"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque dolorem ut fuga impedit, obcaecati aut est inventore voluptatibus eligendi iusto dignissimos consequatur pariatur tenetur vero. Eum aspernatur ad porro a.</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="row"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt inventore, facilis error, tempore nisi optio quasi</div>
    <div class="row"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a read of this http://www.lottejackson.com/learning/an-equal-height-grid-using-flexbox

You need to make the rows display:flex